# Swiftlint output file I am not able to get

Tags: command-line-interface, swiftlint

I am using Swiftlint CLI and it is running successfully and showing the quality issues in terminal.But their is no HTML file generating to see the output .
Can anyone help how to get the output.

Comment: Did you find a an answer to this by any chance?

Comment: if we choose reporter as  `reporter: "html"` it would generate HTML in Xcode build logs and we need to explicitly copy HTML code and save into file. It won't automatically generate html file by it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 12.2016**

HTML is now valid reporter format in SwiftLint

**Original Answer**

The docs don't say anything about reporting in HTML, perhaps you mistake this tool for the Tailor tool at http://tailor.sh?

the reporting format options (specified in .swiftlint.yml) are:
reporter: "xcode" # reporter type (xcode, json, csv, checkstyle, junit)

Answer (score 1):

The html report that SwiftLint creates can be found in the build target log.